# Python with Caffe: The custom data are all zeros when read from solver

Tags: python, caffe, kaggle, lmdb

I try to train Lenet defined here [Solving in Python with LeNet](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/01-learning-lenet.ipynb)
to train the digit-recognition data set on kaggle. I first use the tutorial provided here[Create lmdb](http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/) to transfer data into lmdb format. Then I follow the instruction in link 1(Solving in Python with LeNet) to construct training, testing and solver prototxts. However, when I extract solver from solver.prototxt, I found that each element in image data is zero. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
import pandas as pd
import lmdb
import caffe
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
from caffe import layers as L, params as P
from pylab import *
import os, sys
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
%matplotlib inline

train_original = pd.read_csv(path/to/my/train.csv)
test = pd.read_csv(path/to/my/test.csv)
train_obs, dim = train_data.shape
val_obs, dim = val_data.shape
train_data_array = np.array(train_data, dtype = float32)
train_label_array = np.array(train_label, dtype = float32)
val_data_array = np.array(val_data, dtype = float32)
val_label_array = np.array(val_label, dtype = float32)

train_lmdb_size = train_data_array.nbytes * 10
val_lmdb_size = val_data_array.nbytes * 10
env = lmdb.open('train_lmdb', map_size=train_lmdb_size)
with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
    for i in range(train_num):
        datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
        datum.channels = 1
        datum.height = 28
        datum.width = 28
        datum.data = train_data_array[i].reshape(28, 28).tobytes()  # or .tostring() if numpy < 1.9
        datum.label = int(train_label_array[i])
        str_id = '{:08}'.format(i)
        # The encode is only essential in Python 3
        txn.put(str_id.encode('ascii'), datum.SerializeToString())

env = lmdb.open('test_lmdb', map_size=train_lmdb_size)
with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
    for i in range(val_num):
        datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
        datum.channels = 1
        datum.height = 28
        datum.width = 28
        datum.data = val_data_array[i].reshape(28, 28).tobytes()  # or .tostring() if numpy < 1.9
        datum.label = int(val_label_array[i])
        str_id = '{:08}'.format(i)
        # The encode is only essential in Python 3
        txn.put(str_id.encode('ascii'), datum.SerializeToString())

train_path = 'CNN_training.prototxt'
test_path = 'CNN_testing.prototxt'
train_lmdb_path = 'train_lmdb'
test_lmdb_path = 'test_lmdb'
solver_path = 'CNN_solver.prototxt'

def lenet(lmdb, batch_size):
    # our version of LeNet: a series of linear and simple nonlinear transformations
    n = caffe.NetSpec()

    n.data, n.label = L.Data(batch_size=batch_size, backend=P.Data.LMDB, source=lmdb,
                             transform_param=dict(scale=1./255), ntop=2)

    n.conv1 = L.Convolution(n.data, kernel_size=5, num_output=20, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.pool1 = L.Pooling(n.conv1, kernel_size=2, stride=2, pool=P.Pooling.MAX)
    n.conv2 = L.Convolution(n.pool1, kernel_size=5, num_output=50, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.pool2 = L.Pooling(n.conv2, kernel_size=2, stride=2, pool=P.Pooling.MAX)
    n.fc1 =   L.InnerProduct(n.pool2, num_output=500, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.relu1 = L.ReLU(n.fc1, in_place=True)
    n.score = L.InnerProduct(n.relu1, num_output=10, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
    n.loss =  L.SoftmaxWithLoss(n.score, n.label)

    return n.to_proto()

with open(train_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(lenet(train_lmdb_path, 64)))

with open(test_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(lenet(test_lmdb_path, 100)))

s = caffe_pb2.SolverParameter()
s.random_seed = 0xCAFFE
s.train_net = train_path
s.test_net.append(test_path)
s.test_interval = 500
s.test_iter.append(100)
s.max_iter = 10000
s.type = 'Adam'
s.base_lr = 0.01
s.momentum = 0.75
s.weight_decay = 5e-1
s.lr_policy = 'inv'
s.gamma = 0.0001
s.power = 0.75
s.display = 1000
s.snapshot = 5000
s.snapshot_prefix = 'lin_lnet'
s.solver_mode = caffe_pb2.SolverParameter.CPU
with open(solver_path,'w') as f:
    f.write(str(s))

solver = None
solver = caffe.get_solver(solver_path)
# result in solver.net['data'].data[0] are zeros
print solver.net['data'].data[0]
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
          0.,  0.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a `net.forward()`. You should be able to see your data if everything else is correct.

A simpler and safer way to write to LMDB is using `caffe.io.array_to_datum` as demonstrated [here](http://research.beenfrog.com/code/2015/12/30/write-read-lmdb-example.html).

Comment: @user3162707 please consider "accepting" this answer by clicking the "v" icon beside it.